# Getting "CSRF token missing or incorrect" on obtain token request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest

We are using Django REST Framework and we are using user logins. From a web client we have a login screen and use `obtain_auth_token` from the REST Framework to obtain an api token. The web client uses `XMLHttpRequest`.

It starts out with working fine. The web client obtains a token using username+password and uses that token in the following API calls.

When I return the next day and open a new browser tab and try to log in I get a `403 Forbidden` and the Django logs (and the body reply) says `{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}`

I can see that the incoming request has a `csrftoken` cookie and a `sessionid` cookie. I can see the same cookies if I use the browser "Developer Tools". If I remove those two cookies, it works fine afterwards.

Also, if I launch a private browser window (= incognito), the web app works fine.

I am do not know why those cookies appear, when they appear exactly and why the REST framework do not like them.

I have two suspicions:

1. We also use the Django admin interface. Could it be that the login to the admin interface on the same domain will plant those cookies and somehow interfere with the REST Framework?
2. Something about time passes will make the problem appear? It seems to me that the problem does not appear until "the day after" if I clear the cookies. This might very well be other circumstances tricking me, like point 1 above.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

For reference, some snippes of our Django `setting.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'request_logging.middleware.LoggingMiddleware',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mybackend.apps.MybackendConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'adminsortable',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',
    'storages',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}
```

From `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as restviews

...

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/token-auth/obtain_auth_token', restviews.obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `SessionAuthentication` is the culprit. My guess is that is was added to be able to play with the REST interface from a browser for testing purposes.

So if I remove `SessionAuthentication` it seems to work.

Now the config looks like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}
```